# Swift: Display Image from URL

Tags: swift, image

In Swift 3, I am trying to capture an image from the internet, and have these lines of code:

```
var catPictureURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "http://i.imgur.com/w5rkSIj.jpg")
var catPictureData = NSData(contentsOf: catPictureURL as URL) // nil
var catPicture = UIImage(data: catPictureData as! Data)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The second line is returning nil.

Comment: Why are you not using URL directly in the first line instead of using NSURL just to cast it later?

Comment: I didn't see properly what you were trying to do earlier. I will write a proper answer now.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

There's a few things with your code as it stands:

1. You are using a lot of casting, which is not needed.
2. You are treating your URL as a local file URL, which is not the case.
3. You are never downloading the URL to be used by your image.

The first thing we are going to do is to declare your variable as `let`, as we are not going to modify it later.

```
let catPictureURL = URL(string: "http://i.imgur.com/w5rkSIj.jpg")! // We can force unwrap because we are 100% certain the constructor will not return nil in this case.
```

Then we need to download the contents of that URL. We can do this with the `URLSession` object. When the completion handler is called, we will have a `UIImage` downloaded from the web.

```
// Creating a session object with the default configuration.
// You can read more about it here https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlsessionconfiguration
let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)

// Define a download task. The download task will download the contents of the URL as a Data object and then you can do what you wish with that data.
let downloadPicTask = session.dataTask(with: catPictureURL) { (data, response, error) in
    // The download has finished.
    if let e = error {
        print("Error downloading cat picture: \(e)")
    } else {
        // No errors found.
        // It would be weird if we didn't have a response, so check for that too.
        if let res = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            print("Downloaded cat picture with response code \(res.statusCode)")
            if let imageData = data {
                // Finally convert that Data into an image and do what you wish with it.
                let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
                // Do something with your image.
            } else {
                print("Couldn't get image: Image is nil")
            }
        } else {
            print("Couldn't get response code for some reason")
        }
    }
}
```

Finally you need to call `resume` on the download task, otherwise your task will never start:

`downloadPicTask.resume()`.

All this code may look a bit intimidating at first, but the `URLSession` APIs are block based so they can work asynchronously - If you block your UI thread for a few seconds, the OS will kill your app.

Your full code should look like this:

```
let catPictureURL = URL(string: "http://i.imgur.com/w5rkSIj.jpg")!

// Creating a session object with the default configuration.
// You can read more about it here https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlsessionconfiguration
let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)

// Define a download task. The download task will download the contents of the URL as a Data object and then you can do what you wish with that data.
let downloadPicTask = session.dataTask(with: catPictureURL) { (data, response, error) in
    // The download has finished.
    if let e = error {
        print("Error downloading cat picture: \(e)")
    } else {
        // No errors found.
        // It would be weird if we didn't have a response, so check for that too.
        if let res = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            print("Downloaded cat picture with response code \(res.statusCode)")
            if let imageData = data {
                // Finally convert that Data into an image and do what you wish with it.
                let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
                // Do something with your image.
            } else {
                print("Couldn't get image: Image is nil")
            }
        } else {
            print("Couldn't get response code for some reason")
        }
    }
}

downloadPicTask.resume()
```

Comment: My goodness, This is where I was trying to eventually to get to; your response was way more than I expected to get. This gives me a huge jumpstart. Many, many thanks for your help!

Comment: OMG!! You're a good teacher. I'll try to post all my answers like this whenever I got to, from now on.

Answer (score 39):

```
let url = URL(string: "http://i.imgur.com/w5rkSIj.jpg")
let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url)

if let imageData = data {
    let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
}
```

Comment: `data!` <- This will crash if the download fails for any reason.

Comment: This will also block the main thread with visible dropped frames and overall lag, unless the images are very small.

Answer (score 15):

## Swift

Good solution to extend native functionality by **extensions**

```
import UIKit
    
extension UIImage {
  convenience init?(url: URL?) {
    guard let url = url else { return nil }
            
    do {
      self.init(data: try Data(contentsOf: url))
    } catch {
      print("Cannot load image from url: \(url) with error: \(error)")
      return nil
    }
  }
}
```

#### Usage

Convenience initializer is failable and accepts optional `URL` – approach is safe.

```
imageView.image = UIImage(url: URL(string: "some_url.png"))
```

Comment: is it safe to use when there is lots of data(i.e 1000, 2000 etc) in tableview?

Comment: @PratyushPratik this approach has nothing directly with table view, so you can use, but I don't recommend. For table view flow you need use operations(for canceling) and prefetching.

Answer (score 9):

You could also use Alamofire\AlmofireImage for that task:
https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage

The code should look something like that (Based on the first example on link above):

```
import AlamofireImage

Alamofire.request("http://i.imgur.com/w5rkSIj.jpg").responseImage { response in
    if let catPicture = response.result.value {
        print("image downloaded: \(image)")
    }
}
```

While it is neat yet safe, you should consider if that worth the Pod overhead.
If you are going to use more images and would like to add also filter and transiations I would consider using AlamofireImage

Comment: So how do you save that image to a file?

Answer (score 9):

Use this extension and download image faster.

```
extension UIImageView {
    public func imageFromURL(urlString: String) {

        let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .gray)
        activityIndicator.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height)
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        if self.image == nil{
            self.addSubview(activityIndicator)
        }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: NSURL(string: urlString)! as URL, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

            if error != nil {
                print(error ?? "No Error")
                return
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
                let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                activityIndicator.removeFromSuperview()
                self.image = image
            })

        }).resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you use it !?

Comment: @Ahmadreza you use it like this:  

yourImageViewOutlet.imageFromURL(urlString: yourUrl)

Answer (score 4):

Using Alamofire worked out for me on **Swift 3:**

**Step 1:**

Integrate using pods.

pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.4'

pod 'AlamofireImage', '~> 3.3'

**Step 2:**

import AlamofireImage

import Alamofire

**Step 3:**

```
Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/image/png").responseImage { response in

if let image = response.result.value {
    print("image downloaded: \(image)")
self.myImageview.image = image
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way according to me will be using SDWebImage

Add this to your pod file

```
  pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 4.0'
```

Run pod install

Now import SDWebImage

```
      import SDWebImage
```

Now for setting image from url

```
    imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "http://www.domain/path/to/image.jpg"), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))
```

It will show placeholder image but when image is downloaded it will show  the image from url .Your app will never crash

This are the main feature of SDWebImage

Categories for UIImageView, UIButton, MKAnnotationView adding web image and cache management

**An asynchronous image downloader**

An asynchronous memory + disk image caching with automatic cache expiration handling

A background image decompression

A guarantee that the same URL won't be downloaded several times

A guarantee that bogus URLs won't be retried again and again

A guarantee that main thread will never be blocked
Performances!

Use GCD and ARC

To know more https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Answer (score 3):

Use extension for UIImageView to Load URL Images.

```
let imageCache = NSCache<NSString, UIImage>()

extension UIImageView {

    func imageURLLoad(url: URL) {

        DispatchQueue.global().async { [weak self] in
            func setImage(image:UIImage?) {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self?.image = image
                }
            }
            let urlToString = url.absoluteString as NSString
            if let cachedImage = imageCache.object(forKey: urlToString) {
                setImage(image: cachedImage)
            } else if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url), let image = UIImage(data: data) {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    imageCache.setObject(image, forKey: urlToString)
                    setImage(image: image)
                }
            }else {
                setImage(image: nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We are able to fetch image directly without using Third Party SDK like `'AlamofireImage', 'Kingfisher' and 'SDWebImage'`

**Swift 5**

```
 DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            do{
                  let data = try Data.init(contentsOf: URL.init(string:"url")!)
                   DispatchQueue.main.async {
                      let image: UIImage? = UIImage(data: data)
                      yourImageView.image = image
                   }
             }
            catch let errorLog {
                 debugPrint(errorLog.localizedDescription)
           }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let url = ("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/qualityaudit-678a4.appspot.com/o/profile_images%2FBFA28EDD-9E15-4CC3-9AF8-496B91E74A11.png?alt=media&token=b4518b07-2147-48e5-93fb-3de2b768412d")


self.myactivityindecator.startAnimating()

let urlString = url
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url)


{
(data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("Failed fetching image:", error!)
            return
        }

        guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode == 200 else {
            print("error")
            return
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let image = UIImage(data: data!)
        let myimageview = UIImageView(image: image)
            print(myimageview)
            self.imgdata.image = myimageview.image
self.myactivityindecator.stopanimating()

     }
  }.resume()
```

Answer (score 0):

I use **AlamofireImage** it works fine for me for **Loading url** within **ImageView**, which also has **Placeholder** option.

```
func setImage (){

  let image = “https : //i.imgur.com/w5rkSIj.jpg”
  if let url = URL (string: image)
  {
    //Placeholder Image which was in your Local(Assets)
    let image = UIImage (named: “PlacehoderImageName”)
    imageViewName.af_setImage (withURL: url, placeholderImage: image)
  }

}
```

Note:- Dont forget to Add AlamofireImage in your Pod file as well as in Import Statment

Say Example,

**pod 'AlamofireImage**' within Your PodFile and in ViewController  **import AlamofireImage**