# Convert url to UIImage Swift3

Tags: ios, url, swift3, uiimage

I try to convert url to UIImage by using following code :

```
            let url = URL(string: "http://www.apple.com/euro/ios/ios8/a/generic/images/og.png")
            let sessionTask = URLSession.shared
            let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
            let task = sessionTask.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {(data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) -> Void in
                if (error == nil) {
                    let image: UIImage = UIImage(data: data!)!

                }

            })
            task.resume()
```

but it's not work for me, if-loop is not complied.

Comment: Check what is the value of error object

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39813761/2526932

Comment: This code is working in xcode 8.3

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Try this

```
    let url = URL(string:"http://www.apple.com/euro/ios/ios8/a/generic/images/og.png")
    if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)
    {
      let image: UIImage = UIImage(data: data)
    }
```

**With Background thread**

```
 DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        do
         {
              let data = try Data.init(contentsOf: URL.init(string:"url")!)
               DispatchQueue.main.async {
                  let image: UIImage = UIImage(data: data)
               }
         }
        catch {
               // error
              }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. you can save my time. ><

Comment: Welcome.....@user7778093

Comment: Working Solutions (Xcode 9), Thanks

Comment: What would be the benefit of doing teh conversion in a background thread?

Comment: @QTheGreat It will improve the performance of the application. Ex. Lagging of application during downloading the image.

Comment: @KKRocks small changes in this code . Please add the optional for image let image: UIImage? = UIImage(data: data). This is for Swift 5

Comment: Outstanding work for me

Answer (score 1):

Try this by using [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

```
imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "http://www.apple.com/euro/ios/ios8/a/generic/images/og.png"), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))
```