# ios uploading image to Firebase but it's not when I am trying to download it?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uiimage, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload my userProfile image onto Firebase however, though the upload was successful but when I downloaded it via the download link on the firebase console, it's downloaded as a Document file and not the jpg file that I've uploaded? 
Also, my UIImage took over all my views in the view controller when I set the image to a specific image.

here's my code:

```
@IBAction func registerRegisterButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let userProfileImageRef = self.storage.reference().child("userProfileImage")

    //testing image setup
    self.registerUserProfileImage.image = UIImage(named:"puppy.jpg")

    // Registering user with email
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: registerUserEmailTextField.text!, password: registerUserPasswordTextField.text!) { (user, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print(error)
        } else {
            print("Registration complete")

            // if register succcessful, we upload the user profile image to firebase
            let data = Data()

            //uploading user profile picture
            if let uploadData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.registerUserProfileImage.image!) {
                userProfileImageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in

                    if error != nil {
                        print(error)
                        return
                    } else {
                        print("Success upload!")
                        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "registrationCompleteSegue", sender: self)
                    }
                })

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help in advance

Comment: And how you are retrieving it?

Comment: @richie Im just testing it using the download URL on my firebase

Comment: Its not clear what you are asking. Explain it more

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to download the URL of Image and setting it into ImageView. If yes, then create a `meta data` of type `StorageMetadata` and set the `content type` as `image/jpeg`. Then pass it in `putData` method of Firebase Reference and get the ImageURL with the `metadata` parameter of putData method.

```
let metaData = StorageMetadata()
metaData.contentType = "image/jpg"

        if let uploadData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.registerUserProfileImage.image!, 0.8) as NSData {

           userProfileImageRef.putData(uploadData as Data, metadata: metaData, completion: { (metadata, error) in

                if error != nil {
                    print(error)
                    return
                } else {
                    print("Success upload!")
                    var imageURL = (metadata?.downloadURLs?[0].absoluteString)!  //Here's your image url. Then just set it to ImageView

                    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "registrationCompleteSegue", sender: self)
                }
           })
       }
```

For setting Image with URL. Kindly check this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/43486949/4608334