# display the image from array in swift

Tags: ios

I have stored a data as below:-

viewmodel:-

```
     typealias dummyDataSource1 =  QM_RestaurtantDataSourceModel
        extension dummyDataSource1{

            func getJsonDataStored1() ->Array<Dictionary<String,String>>{

                let jsonArray = [["name":"Anjapar","imageurl":"https://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/9-credit-1.jpg","city":"Musheireb,Qatar"],["name":"Aryaas","imageurl":"https://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/9-credit-1.jpg","city":"Al Muntazah,Qatar"],["name":"India Coffee","imageurl":"","city":"Doha,Qatar"],["name":"Saravana","imageurl":"https://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/9-credit-1.jpg","city":"Al Muntazah,Qatar"],["name":"Tea Time","imageurl":"","city":"Old Airport,Qatar"]] as Array<Dictionary<String,String>>

                return jsonArray
            }
```

i need to display the imageurl:-image in UIImgeView .How to do
i tried with code:-

```
  @IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var city: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageurl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var images: UIImageView!



    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    func setRestaurtantData(restaurtant:QM_RestaurtantModel)
    {
        self.name.text = restaurtant.name
        self.city.text = restaurtant.city
        self.imageurl.text = restaurtant.imageurl


    }
```

my model:-

var name :String!
        var city :String!
        var imageurl :String!

```
init?(dictionary :JSONDictionary) {

    guard let name = dictionary["name"] as? String,
        let imageurl = dictionary["imageurl"] as? String,
        let city = dictionary["city"] as? String else {
            return
    }

    self.name = name
    self.city = city
    self.imageurl = imageurl
```

}

i getting the value as string ,but i need to display the image

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: @Anbu.karthik i have updated my code.please check......

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift 3: Display Image from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39813497/swift-3-display-image-from-url)

Comment: @avaharper222 - plz see the dupliacte answer of `extension UIImageView {
    public func imageFromURL(urlString: String) {` code, it will helps you