# How can I use a URL for an image in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, url, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve certain data from my Firebase Database - the profile image. As you can see, this is from a UITableViewCell. I have an @IBOutlet for my imageView I want to cover.

As the view awakens, you can see that I go through, and make sure that I can get the information. I know how to retrieve data from Firebase, but not photo URLs, and then convert to the photo itself.

I'm not sure why it isn't working. I am getting an error, and will show it below. There is a possibility it is because of the URL unwrapping stuff, or as if the Firebase isn't formatted correctly, which I think it is, though.

Error Message : `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase
import Firebase

class ProfileCellControler: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var name : UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var rating : UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var imageViewPro : UIImageView!

    var databaseRefer : DatabaseReference!
    var databaseHandle : DatabaseHandle!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        var urlString = ""
        let urll = URL(string: urlString)!

        databaseRefer = Database.database().reference()
        let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid

        databaseHandle = databaseRefer.child("Users").child(userID).child("Profile").child("Profile Name").observe(.value, with: { (data) in
            print(String((data.value as? String)!))
            self.name.text = "\(String((data.value as? String)!))"
            print("Done")
        })

        databaseHandle = databaseRefer.child("Users").child(userID).child("Profile").child("Stars").observe(.value, with: { (data) in
            print(String((data.value as? String)!))
            if ((String((data.value as? String)!)) == "N/A") {
                self.rating.text = "No Rating"
            } else {
                self.rating.text = "\(String((data.value as? String)!)) ★"
            }
            print("Done")
        })

        databaseHandle = databaseRefer.child("Users").child(userID).child("Profile").child("Profile Image").observe(.value, with: { (data) in
            print(String((data.value as? String)!))
            print("Done \(String((data.value as? String)!))")
            urlString = (String((data.value as? String)!))
        })

        ImageService.downloadImage(withURL: urll) { (image) in
            self.imageViewPro.image = image
        }

        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

[image: Take a look at my code, and use the code here if you don't understand]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift 3: Display Image from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39813497/swift-3-display-image-from-url)

Comment: Your string can't be parsed to a URL and that's why it is crashing.

Comment: connect through teamviewer i will see and fix your issue

Comment: It is crashing because your string can't be parsed to a URL

Answer (score 1):

The string for the URL is found nil because you are creating the call to download the image for your url before the `urll` has been initialized with a value from the database in:

```
  databaseHandle = databaseRefer.child("Users").child(userID).child("Profile").child("Profile Image").observe(.value, with: { (data) in
            print(String((data.value as? String)!))
            print("Done \(String((data.value as? String)!))")
            urlString = (String((data.value as? String)!))
        })
```

`observe(.value, with: )` Is an asynchronous operation thus

```
ImageService.downloadImage(withURL: urll) { (image) in
            self.imageViewPro.image = image
    }
```

Is being called before `observe(.value, with:)` is resolved. I would recommend moving the callback for the download URL inside of the completion for `.observe(:value, :with)` or using grand central dispatch to control the flow better.

As a side note, I highly recommend [SDWebImage](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage) for handling your image downloading needs as it is configurable with a default image for situations such as this when the image fails to load.

Answer (score 0):

Import KingFisher to make your life easier and then..

1. Download string representation of image from Firebase asynchronically.
2. Assign downloaded image to imageView with **.kf.setImage** method.

Comment: This answer will be problematic because neither Firebase or Firestore was designed to store large single strings and image sizes may go well beyond their limit, which will crash the app. The better solution is to store images in [Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage), which is what it was designed for,